# Corda execute several flows from one flow

Tags: corda

Can I execute several flows from ONE corda flow? 
Can I create several different transactions for different states from one flow.
The task is connected with creation different stated into one flow.
Any examples? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do that with the help of subflows. refer [this](https://docs.corda.net/api-flows.html#api-flows) and the

[flow cook book](https://docs.corda.net/flow-cookbook.html)

Comment: I mean different. For instance in my corda APP I have FlowA and FlowB. From corda console I run FlowA and FlowA have to execute FlowB internally. Does it possible?

Comment: Yes. from the web server you do a rpcops.startFlow(Pass your initiator class with params). similarly from can do that with subflow(Pass your initiator class with params) inside your flow.

Comment: @Kid101 does this ensure execution of FlowA is continued only after sublow(FlowB) is completed?